# Issue with store frontend view

Tags: magento2, 404, 404-page

I created stores with script in Magento 2.1
But I face an issue when I tried to access the store it returns 404 pages.

I tried to create a store from admin, and the store i created from admin. It works in frontend.

I do reindexing, Upgrade, Compile, and every basic step in Magento 2 debug.

I follow this to create a store view.

https://gist.github.com/0-Sony/1297fd13e11e9b901fa403a618b6cee5